# How to Give Discount Fees From Checkout to Payment Gateways in Magento

Tags: magento

Where do magento fetch the grand total and sub total while to takes the amount from check out to payment gateway?

I would like to give a deduction(some amount for each payment methods) for each order from magento checkout. So i have write a Observer for fee deduction to each orders in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily setup discount fees based on **payment methods** using **shopping cart price rules** which is built in functionality in magento.Check this magento wiki [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them)

The link describes how to set shopping cart price rules.

Comment: Yes. i Agree your answer, But i have customizing the new module for custom discount price for my store. So i have following the below reference link for discount price http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total. In Cart and Checkout page and everything is alright for subtotal deduction and works well, But When i have redirecting to paypal the subtotal value not deducting with discount price. So that i am looking so far.. can you help me ?

Comment: In case of paypal during order creation magento makes a api call.The api request contains a field discount_amount which represents the discount amoount.You need to add your custom discount fee to this field( discount_amount).

Comment: Ok. But if already magento have default discount values what we do ?

Comment: You need to add custom discount fee to already computed  discount value.Take a look at the file "app/core/code/mage/paypal/model/cart.php".I think you can override this file to include your discount

Comment: Yes Correct, But i don't know right method to override the paypal Cart.php file. can you help me please?

Comment: I need to add extra line for paypal line item for discount with discount price.